# Kohana ORM select records by date

Tags: mysql, date, orm, kohana

I need to get all rows on the specified day, using Kohana ORM. Date field name is 'created_date', stored date format is '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ('Y-m-d H:i:s').

```
$day = '2015-07-17'; // for example

$items_filtered = ORM::factory($this->_object_name)
->where(DB::expr("DATE_FORMAT('created_date', '%Y-%M-%d')"), '=', $day)
->order_by('created_date', 'DESC')
->find_all();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You would want to use a between query like below:

```
$dayst = '2015-07-17 00:00:00'
$dayen = '2015-07-17 23:59:59'

$items_filtered = ORM::factory($this->_object_name)
->where('created_date', 'between', array($dayst, $dayen))
->order_by('created_date', 'DESC')
->find_all();
```